# fecha date ("y,m,d) pasarlo a mes

Tags: date

hola tengo en mi base de datos un campo fecha donde se almacena con $fecha=date("Y-m-d); y quiero que en mi tabla haya uno donde muestre la fecha completa y otro donde muestre solo el mes como lo convierto

$fecha=date("Y-m-d ");

Fecha
 Mes
mis campos en las tablas donde se almacena fecha y mes en este caso solo fecha

$so = "SELECT s.Id_folio, s.fecha, la seleccion desde la base de datos con el campo fecha

aqui muestro la fecha que mande a llamar desde la base de datos
ahora lo que quiero es mediante un select del campo fecha mostrar solo el mes

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A que te referis con como lo convierto? automaticamente en la base de datos? al cargar los datos? que db estas usando?

Comment: al parecer usas PHP, en este caso tu guardas la fecha en tu base de datos y al hacer el select puedes sustraer el mes o el dia o el año

Comment: al hacer el select como lo hago porq hago primero un select donde mando a llamar toda la fecha pero para solo el mes?

Comment: Hola deberías subir el código que haz realizado para ver como te podemos ayudar, saludos.

Comment: $so = "SELECT s.Id_folio, s.fecha, g.Id_gerencia,g.Nombre_gerencia, s.descripcion_trabajo,

Comment: <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Solicitud Servicio</th>
        <th scope="col">Folio</th>
        <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
          <th scope="col">Mes</th>
         <th scope="col">Gerencia</th>
        <th scope="col">Área</th>
      
      esta es mi tabla y abajo mando a llamar la fecha entera

Comment: <td><?php echo $i["fecha"];?></td>
       <td><?php echo date('F') ;?></td> puse este para que me mostrara el mes de cada solicitud pero me muestra el mes actual

Comment: Hola alondra, el código lo debes de subir en el detalle de la pregunta, toda información que nos sirva para ayudarte debe ir incluida en la pregunta, revisa otras preguntas y ve el formato que ocupan como suben la información etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando obtienes un dato puedes decidir como se muestra un ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM registro WHERE FechaHora >= CURDATE()"
```

Comment: <td><?php echo $i["fecha"];?></td> esta es para mandar a llamar toda mi fecha desde la base de datos pero ahora solo quiero mandar a llamr solo el mes

Comment: <?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>     esto seria el resultado (2000-01-01 00:00:00)

Comment: solo quiero hacer un select desde el campo fecha de la base de datos que muestre solo el mes de cada solicitud

Comment: curdate() para que es en especifico

Comment: solo usa un formato trae toda la fecha pero solo muestra el mes

Comment: pero esa seleccion como la mando a llamar desde un td?

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `datetime` FROM `table`");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$date = date_create($row[0]);

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

## output: 2012-03-24 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');

## output: 24/03/2012 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y');

## output: 24/03/12

echo date_format($date, 'g:i A');

## output: 5:45 PM

echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');

## output: 05:45pm

echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');

## output: 5:45pm on Saturday 24th March 2012